# Rearranging an inputted string

Tags: java, object

D2L does not know how to present student names to the instructors who need to find these names 
for grade entry. The form is `first name, a full middle name, last name, a comma, and an email address`, which makes the `middle name` appear as the `last name`. The developers of D2L never 
learned the proper technique for presenting names.

Write a Java program to help change this mess by placing the `last name` first, followed by a `comma`, the `first name`, and the `middle initial` followed by a `period`. Your dialog should look exactly like this for the given input (the email address must not be in the new name representation):

Enter a name like D2L shows them:

`Casey Carter, Cartwright, ccc@email.arizona.edu`

Output:-

`Cartwright, Casey C.`

I'm not really sure how to even start this. Can someone give me some hints so I can get it rolling?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework question? What have you tried so far? Which approaches have you tried? I also recommend you this site: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: And [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25905844/edit) to change the horrible layout.

Comment: So far all i have is the system printing the input request, but I'm not sure how to separate the string based on the different names and rearrange them how the problem asks.

Comment: Look at the API documentation of class [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), it contains many methods to do things with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the input string and split it about the `comma` , example:-

```
String s1="Casey Carter, Cartwright, ccc@email.arizona.edu";
String[] arr=s1.split(","); // you will get each individual input terms i.e first name , lastname, email in string array
```

Then you can build a string using it:-

```
String s2=arr[1]+","+arr[0];
```

Note that this will build string `Cartwright, Casey Carter` to build string `Cartwright, Casey C` you need to further manipulate the string consisting of `firstname`, which I leave for you to explore. (Hint:- you can use [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to remove extra chars from the end of `firstname`).